# OSX Reset Home Permissions and ACLs - how long should it take?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, permissions

Having screwwed up my permissions by trying to have two users accessing one home folder I'm now going through the process of reseting my main user home permissions via the OSX install disk utilities, which seems to be taking a while.

Does this process take a while to do, though I assume it depends on how many files I have in the folder, which in my case is a good few 100 GBs.

At what point should I be concerned that it may have got stuck and thus reset my computer and try again?

I assume, though not sure that if the little circle indicator is still moving then it's not completely frozen, but as there's no progress bar or details I'm not sure how true that is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can’t fix permissions in your home folder with disk utility. It can only fix permissions for files installed by system.
To fix permissions inside user home folder you should boot with your installation disc and use reset password utility, there is option not to reset password, but to fix permissions for certain user.
And duration of permissions check and repair really does depend on how many files do you have, so it’s difficult to figure out is it frozen in your case or not.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, sorry, badly worded explaination.

Thanks for the reply., confirms my thought, I do have a lot of stuff in my home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many files you have.  If you have a ton of smaller files in your profile folder (bits of source code, multi-part archives) it'll take quite awhile.  If you're a normal user, it shouldn't take too long at all. Maybe 15 minutes, at the most.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here, or would `sudo chown [your username] ~/` from your home folder do the job?